# What is the network controller and how does it relate to Wi-Fi?

Tags: drivers, wifi

I am working on getting wireless up and running on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. In this 
[tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlLS8d4Z09c), the guy says "your network controller is your Wi-Fi." To me, that seems to imply that the network controller is the piece of hardware that handles your wireless connection. Does the network controller also handle your Ethernet connection? When I run `lspci` and `grep` for network I see that my Network controller is a Realtek Semiconductor Co. device. What exactly does that device do? My Ethernet is working fine. Do I need to find a driver that will handle both wired and wireless connections for this network controller? Or do I need a Wi-Fi driver for the network controller because the network controller only handles Wi-Fi.

```
$ lspci -vvnn | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:818b]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a "softer" search pattern, there are 2 hw controllers for me Ethernet and Network, each hw device requires a driver.

Here's mine.

```
$ lspci -vvnn |grep -i net
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
$
```

Answer (score 1):

> To me, that seems to imply that the network controller is the piece of hardware that handles your wireless connection.

Yes.

> Does the network controller also handle your ethernet connection?

No. `lspci` identifies that as an *Ethernet controller*.

> When I run lspci and grep for network I see that my Network controller is a Realtek Semiconductor Co. device. What exactly does that device do?

That's your wifi chipset, it might be better to think of it as a "Wifi controller".

> Do I need to find a driver that will handle both wired and wireless connections for this network controller? Or do I need a wifi driver for the network controller because the network controller only handles wifi.

The `03:00.0` at the beginning of the `lspci` output is a bus/slot number for the device.  Most likely, there is already a driver loaded.  To check, look in `/sys/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/driver/module/drivers`; it will probably contain a symlink reference to something in `/sys/pci/drivers`.

> Or do I need a wifi driver for the network controller because the network controller only handles wifi.

Unless you have some unusual hardware the kernel should already have a driver for both the ethernet and wifi controllers loaded.