# Can I deactivate the broadcom driver if I have a Realtek wireless card?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, wifi

I am trying to get my wireless working on ubuntu 12.04. If I run lshw I see this output, indicating a Realtek wireless card.

```
       *-network UNCLAIMED
            description: Network controller
            product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            version: 00
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list
            configuration: latency=0
            resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0400000-f0403fff
```

If I run "Additional Drivers" I see that it has a Broadcom driver installed and activated. Will this driver interfere with a Realtek driver? The wireless is not working on my computer so I need to install an additional driver. is there any good reason to activate or deactivate the broadcom driver?

Comment: Just FYI, Realtek isn't usually seen making wireless card and that device you are showing is in fact a ethernet card.

Comment: @Braiam I thought that was not the case? I asked about this on these forums and got a different answer. Can you help clarify? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116154/what-is-the-network-controller-and-how-does-it-relate-to-wi-fi

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I looked about the internets and found this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1239578). Apparently only mainline kernel has a mock up of the required drivers for the card to be detected and used. Realtek released the driver recently and that's why it isn't recognized nor any module loaded in stable kernels.

I would recommend to [install the mainline kernels](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) and report any issue you find with the card to the respective places.